# inline translation not working in magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento

inline translation in magento is not working for the data which is loaded from ajax.

I had used following for installation:
      http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-language-translation-for-custom-module-step-by-step-guide/

I have created following template file for the display of my product details.

`magento\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

it has following code:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $this->__('desired word') ?>
```

I have created a custom module for inline translation to load csv file for all my custom modules.
  `\magento\app\code\local\Translations\Inline\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Translations_Inline>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Translations_Inline>
  </modules>
   <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <translations>
                    <files>
                        <default>Translations.csv</default>
                    </files>
                 </translations>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
               <translations>
                    <files>
                        <default>Translations.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </translations>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <inline>
        <class>Translations_Inline_Helper</class>
      </inline>
     </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

To activate module,
    \magento\app\etc\modules\Translations_Inline.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Translations_Inline>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Translations_Inline>
      </modules>
 </config>
```

I have added Translation.csv in following folders:

\magento\app\locale\en_US

\magento\app\locale\zh_HK

So,after enabling inline translation from admin side for English as well Chinese storeview,its working well but my question is what if my data in view.hmtl is loaded from ajax not like 
     __('desired word');?>

fox exmaple if view.phtml is as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var url_magento = '<?php echo        Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>';    

  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
  j(document).ready(function()
  {
getcontent();

 });
 function getcontent()
 {

jQuery.ajax({
    url:url_magento+'hi.php',
    type:'POST',
    beforeSend: function(){
                jQuery('#product_app').html('loading');
                },      
    ajaxError : function() {                
                jQuery('#product_app').html('Error: Can not load page');
            },
    success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                jQuery('#product_app').html(data);          
            }
        }); 

    }
</script>
<div id='product_app'></div>
```

Now hi.php is as follows:

```
 <?php  
   echo "hi.This is the page that gives product's detail";
 ?>
```

so,I want inline translation working for this data too.or is there any other way to load data of ajax in php in form of echo.
  You are free to ask more details.i try to add most of the needed data to configure inline translation.hoping for the answer asap.thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifically speaking about inline translation, you are correct that this code is not translatable. This is because Magento has not been initialized within `hi.php` - you are just outputting text. What you will need to do is set up a controller to handle your AJAX calls which then *will* have Mage initialized and therefore you will have access to the entire Magento framework.

Note that I also don't use inline translation for most things, rather I define the translations in my theme's `translate.csv` file.

For a tutorial on creating a controller, see a tutorial like [this](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller) or there are many others floating around.

Comment: hey thank you.you said that you define the translations in your theme's translate.csv file.can you explain this in more detail?